# Why the keras layers name's isn't renamed?

Tags: keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I want to get below model

```
def define_stacked_model(members):
    for i in range(len(members)):
        model = members[i]
        for layer in model.layers:
            # делаем слои нетренируемыми (обучаем ток мета-модель)
            layer.trainable = False
            # переименовываем слои для уникальности имен
            layer._name = 'ensemble_' + str(i+1) + '_' + layer.name
    # многоголовый ансамблевый вход
    ensemble_visible = [model.input for model in members]
    print(type(ensemble_visible))
    # мерджим аут
    ensemble_outputs = [model.output for model in members]
    merge = concatenate(ensemble_outputs)
    ### Скрытый слой
    hidden = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
    output = Dense(1, activation='relu')(hidden)
    model = Model(inputs=ensemble_visible, outputs=output)
    # отрисовываем
    plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='model_graph.png')
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

where the members is the keras models as written below

```
`[<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x2a3a8d8bd90>,
 <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x2a3aa189cd0>,
 <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x2a3aa154e50>,
 <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x2a3aa683220>,
 <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x2a3ac6074f0>]`
```

And when i try to start this model, i get the error below

```
`ValueError: The name "input_1" is used 5 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.`
```

I understand that mistake within ensemble_visible, they are all the same, but i don't understand why this happens. I renamed the layers for every model and every layer, so why?